# Use a partial with a form within a form using form_for and fields_for (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, form-for, renderpartial, fields-for

in my app I have tickets that can be commented, I would like to force the user to insert a comment when inserting a new ticket or when updating one, so I'm trying to have the comments to be created with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for`.

Although i use the same `comments/form` partial for inserting also comments that don't belong to an update or to a ticket creation, so in this case the partial `comments/form` should contain a `form_for`.

The `if` clause is clear, if there's a `ticket_form` object available (this is passed by the renderer from). Although I'm not sure about how to handle these two without replicating the form fields data.

Here's my `comments/form` controller, which of course doesn't work:

```
  .comment-form
  - if ticket_form.nil? 
    = simple_fields_for @new_comment do |f|
  - else
    = simple_form_for @new_comment do |f|
  = f.input :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => @new_comment.commentable_id
    .row
      .span7
        = f.input :text, :input_html => { :rows => 5, :class => "span7"}, :label => false
      .span4
        = f.file_field :image
    .row
      .span7= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => "Submitting…"
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: just to make it super clear, that's the view written in `HAML` and I'm using `simple_form`